# Separate Email for a country

Tags: magento2, order-email, newsletter, place-order, newsletter-subscriber

My client wants to send a different order confirmation email for a country. Like we have a US store and receive orders from Russia customs should receive the email that we don't ship them in Russian.

Is this possible?

Please help

Comment: if you are not shipping in russia then why taking order from russia? please prevent to place order from russia.

Answer (score 0):

If that is a customer requirement

Declare a new template with the non-US order confirmation

you can either create a Plugin or override
**magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender**

In **Send** method you are getting order object , there you can check shipping address country if that is non-US then use the new order template else don't